# How to shift int64 value to unsigned int64 space without changing the order?

Tags: c++, casting, unsigned-integer

For example:

1. INT64_MIN to 0
2. 0 to INT64_MAX+1
3. INT64_MAX to UINT64_MAX

Below is my code:

```
uint64_t int64ToUint64(int64_t value)
{
    uint64_t uvalue = value - std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();
    return uvalue;
}
```

It works, but there is signed integer overflow, and per C++ standard, signed integer overflow is behavior undefined. Any other solutions without integer overflow?

Comment: How portable do you need it? I'm pretty sure the "signed overflow" is undefined for two reasons: 1. Risk of trapping overflows (not a problem in most cases), 2. One's complement vs. two's complement -> presence/absence of negative zero -> uncertainty of what bit pattern leads to what value. If you are only concerned with "common" processors such as x86, ARM, 68K, 29K, MIPS, I'd say it's "safe" (if MIPS is told to not generate overflow traps)

Comment: @MatsPetersson actually we are only on x86 rhel6. Just curious if there is better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a definite solution. Perhaps converting to unsigned first and then subtracting the offset as an unsigned value would be more reliable (but I'm not sure that is well defined for values that are outside of 0..INT64_MAX either.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: No, it is not safe. Compilers make optimizations assuming you don't invoke undefined behavior; breaking such assumptions will sometimes lead to code with different behavior from your intentions.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: It is safe. There's no undefined behavior. Both the conversion of the input to unsigned and the conversion of offset to unsigned are well-defined. The unsigned difference is modulo 2^64 which is also defined. (It's also correct - see Michael Burr's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since conversion from signed to unsigned types is well defined and since there's no overflow on unsigned arithmetic, you can do what you want safely by first converting the signed value to an unsigned type:

```
uint64_t int64ToUint64(int64_t value)
{
    uint64_t uvalue = value;

    uvalue += INT64_MAX;
    uvalue += 1;

    return uvalue;
}
```

Comment: Cool. How about convert uint64 to int64?

Answer (score -2):

```
uint64_t int64ToUint64(int64_t value){
    uint64_t res = *(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&value));
    return res ^ numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();
}
int64_t uint64ToInt64(uint64_t value){
    value ^= numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();
    return *(reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&value));
}
```

Comment: The goal was to avoid Undefined behavior. Furthermore, this breaks the order: `int64ToUint64(-1) > int64ToUint64(0)`.

Comment: I did not understand the question properly. I thought about bit order. So, I corrected the code.

Comment: I think it's still broken for one's complement, but that's theoretical. The `reinterpret_cast` is still UB, I'm afraid.